# How to make conditional cascade validation (Hibernate)?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

I have a class similar to this:

```
public Foo {

  @Valid
  private Bar bar;
  private Long barId;
}
```

so when I validate class Foo, class Bar is validated as well. But sometimes I don't want class Bar to be validated (eg when it's not possible to correct bad values) when I validate Foo. Can I do something similar to this:

```
@Valid(when="barId is null")
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no support for conditions in @Valid. I think as a workaround you can try define your [custom constraint](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints) @ConditionalBarValid. You can apply it on class level:

```
@ConditionalBarValid
public Foo {

    private Bar bar;
    private Long barId;
}
```

So your constraint validator will have access to entire Foo object and it will be able:

- check if barId is null
- get an instance of Validator and force validation for **bar** object

Your **ConditionalBarValidator.isValid(...)** implementation may looks like this :

```
// case when foo is not null and foo.getBarId is null
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
boolean validationResult = validator.validate(foo.getBar()).isEmpty();
```